# C# null DateTime optional parameter

Tags: c#, datetime

I've a problem in C# where I want to pass a DateTime object as an optional parameter for a function as so:

```
public bool SetTimeToNow(DateTime? now = null)
{
    if (now == null)
    {
       now = new DateTime();
       now = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

which works fine but when I want to use the object now as follows:

```
seconds = ( byte ) now.Second;
```

I get an error Error:

```
'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for
'Second' and no extension method 'Second' accepting a first argument of type
'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing using 
 directive or an assembly reference?
```

Also seconds is initialized as a byte by the way.

Any help or advice how to overcome this error?

Comment: You need to access the value using the `Value` property.

Comment: After you set now to DateTime.Now you can parse DateTime? to DateTime. Then you can work with now.Second (you don't need the nullable DateTime at this point anymore). Call now.Value to get the not-nullable DateTime ;)

Comment: Note that you don't need `now = new DateTime();`, that line can be safely removed entirely, it will have no impact on your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data type is `DateTime?` (aka `Nullable<DateTime>`), you first have to check if it has a value (call`.HasValue`) and then access its value by calling `Value`:

```
seconds = (byte) = now.Value.Second;
```

<sup>(Note that that code will throw an exception when `now` is null, so you have to check `HasValue`!)</sup>

Or, if you want to default it:

```
seconds = (byte) = now.HasValue ? now.Value.Second : 0;
```

Which is the same as:

```
seconds = (byte) = now != null ? now.Value.Second : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.?` and `??` operator

```
seconds = (byte) (now?.Second ?? 0); // if seconds is type of byte
seconds = now?.Second; // if seconds is type of byte?
```

Any way using default parameter seems unnecessary to me. You can use method overloads instead of using nullable date time.

```
public bool SetTimeToNow()
{
   return SetTimeToNow(DateTime.Now); // use default time.
}

public bool SetTimeToNow(DateTime now)
{
    // Do other things outside if
}
```